# Erro ao utilizar dicionário em um método IQueryable.Select() para projetar colunas escolhidas em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

O fragmento de código abaixo tem como objetivo utilizar o método Select() para realizar projeções genéricas de colunas em uma consulta, de acordo com uma lista de nomes de colunas fornecida. O programa funciona bem se todas as colunas são do tipo 'string', mas dispara a exceção abaixo quando alguma coluna é de um tipo diferente, como 'Guid'.

> Expression of type 'System.Guid' cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Object' of method 'Void Add(System.String, System.Object)

Como posso resolver este problema?

```
public static IQueryable EscolherColunas<T>(this IQueryable<T> baseQuery, String[] columns) where T : class 
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    var addMethod = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>).GetMethod("Add");
    List<ElementInit> dicadds = new List<ElementInit>();
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        var eKey = Expression.Constant(column);
        var eValue = Expression.Property(parameter, column);
        var eAdd = Expression.ElementInit(addMethod, eKey, eValue);
        dicadds.Add(eAdd);
    }
    var dicinit = Expression.ListInit(Expression.New(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)), dicadds);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(dicinit, parameter);
    return baseQuery.Select(selector);
}
```

Comment: Como você chama o método?